# Download Nuget Package from Github nuget registery using PowerShell, Error : Find-Package: No match was found/

Tags: powershell, github, nuget

I am trying to download using `PowerShell` a `nuget` package from my `Github` nuget registry, but without success, receiving a weird error message.

1. **First**, here's my environment:

[image]

2. **Second**, here's the code I'm executing:

   ````
   $patToken = "<MY_PAT_TOKEN>" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force -Verbose
   $packageSourceCreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("nuget.pkg.github.com\<MY_USERNAME>", $patToken) -Verbose
   $packageSource = Register-PackageSource -Name MyNugetSource -Location $packageSourceUrl -ProviderName NuGet -Trusted -Credential $packageSourceCreds -Verbose 
   $Find-Package -Name <PACKAGE_NAME> -Source MyNugetSource -Credential $packageSourceCreds -Verbose```
   ````

I'm receiving this error saying that:

**`Find-Package: No match was found for the specified search criteria and package name '<PACKAGE_NAME>'. Try Get-PackageSource to see all available registered package sources.`**

I'm pretty sure of the correctness of the name of the package and of my credentials, is there something I'm missing or that I'm doing incorrectly ?

Comment: Does searching the entire registry return any packages? `Find-Package -Source MyNugetSource -Name *`. Do you get a different error if you feed it the wrong credentials on purpose?

Comment: @Cpt.Whale I get nothing when doing `Find-Package -Source MyNugetSource -Name *`
When entering wrong credentials on purpose I get the same error as if I entered my real creds